# In terms of responsive design, how do you handle high resolution phones, such as the Galaxy S4?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Historically, you'd use media queries based of pixel width to determine what display the end user will get. However, that doesn't/won't work when you are using a higher resolution device such as a Galaxy S4 (1080x1920) resolution.

How do you handle this?

Comment: AFAIK it still works, because a pixel is not a pixel http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: First off, the viewport is already going to be scaled on high resolution devices like this, usually to `980px`.  You can change this to use the native resolution.  Depending on your needs, base stuff on `ems` and this problem works itself out automatically.  Most devices have `1em` set to a readable size.  This can be come a real problem with ads though, which are always fixed to pixel size.

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing. You saved me the time for research!

Answer (score 25):

What makes you think  media queries won't work?

Apparently, Galaxy S4's CSS pixel ratio is 3.0, therefore, while its physical resolution is 1080x1920, its CSS resolution is still 360x640 - similar to Galaxy S3.

There are also media queries that test for pixel density. They may help you to serve high-res pictures or vector graphics to hi-dpi devices.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Samsung

http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

Plus, take a look at this article:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/

Awesome database of screen specifications

http://screensiz.es/phone

Comment: Thanks for the answers all, this makes a lot more sense to me now.

Comment: Wikipedia link is dead, I think you can find the same content on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_high-definition_smartphone_displays

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what framework you are using for your responsive design, but using Bootstrap I added this to `<head>` and it worked for me:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

There's some good information about this here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying/

Specifically, the section under the topic "Viewports" addresses your question.