# Media queries for a mobile HTML5 app

Tags: css, html, cordova, responsive-design, media-queries

I've basically gone mad trying to figure/google it out. iOS device are not an issue since there aren't so many and its easy to set for every single one, but the android and possibly BlackBerry come into the game...

Basically I have 4 sizes (S, M, L, XL) of CSS, but then there comes a phone like "HTC One" that has full HD (1920x1080) and 4.7 inches... how to i count this in? is there like a framework that covers most frames. HJow do i approach this? How do i cover most devices?

Cheers,
K

Comment: You can use `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` and `min-resolution` in your media queries to target high-res devices. See here: http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

Comment: You may find an adequate answer to your question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490175/in-terms-of-responsive-design-how-do-you-handle-high-resolution-phones-such-as

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can say the way I personally handle this is something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/base.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/720_grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 720px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/986_grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 986px)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/1236_grid.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1236px)" >
```

So I basically have three CSS files, and depending on the width of the screen, each of these is automatically loaded.   The last one is for anything 1236 or higher.

Is this what you are looking for...   or am I missing what you are asking?

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your comment, but what i need is for mobile devices that have both screen size and DPI... I think that this solution is only for desktop screens with similar DPI. Like i said above "but then there comes a phone like "HTC One" that has full HD (1920x1080) and 4.7 inches", in your example if he would to use "1236_grid.css" he would get really tiny elements....

Comment: @Charlie74: This is a very bad way to use media queries! Firstly  because separating your styles in different files will cause additional requests as a browser will load all CSS files (not only the one matching by its rule). Secondly using only `min-width` leads to all styles applied (and overwritten) which may cause the browser to re-render the page up to four times in your case. Both things should absolutely be avoided, especially for mobile devices! And last but not least one should use EMs instead of pixels for media query rules.

Comment: @Charlie74 and Netsurfer. Media queries can be used in the header so only one css file is loaded. There is a downside when the browser window is resized but apart from developers checking responsiveness of a site who will do that more than once.

Answer (score 2):

In your media query, you can use `max-device-width` instead of `max-width`. `max-width` will target anything that supports media queries, but `max-device-width` will target based on screen instead of window.
"Describes the width of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window)." *source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
@media all and (max-device-width:1920px){
 /* this will target any device up to 1920px */
}
```

Or if you know the resolution, you can combine them:

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-device-width:1920px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

OK well, I think that create a special css stylesheet for each size of screen doesn't match perfectly the "responsive design" therms. Then you should create first a css for your site  based on the largest screen, or **start from the littlest (mobile first)** your site will be used with. Then you just have to add a **media queries** block in your css like this :
`@media all and (max-width: *Size of screen*px) { *Your css here* }`
to change an element each time  he looks weird or uniform.

With this tricks, also use the **viewport meta-tag** `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` wich will disable scale for the user and fit automatically the window to fit your site perfectly on **every screen** (even smart phone).

I don't even know if it could really help you, but I think that's it's important to mark that make a specific stylesheet for particulars size is really not the good way, cause **there's one million of different screen size**.

Then you could also use a **css grid**, like [960 Grid System](http://960.gs) or [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/).

Take a look here for more informations : http://socialdriver.com/2012/06/a-responsive-web-design-tutorial-for-beginners/

Comment: +1 for mentioning Twitter Bootstrap and 960 Grid System, better to rely on CSS frameworks than rolling up your own.
I'd prefer **not** to go by your first paragraph though.
And as for the second para, it's always good to not mention maximum-scale so the user can zoom in if for some reason he needs text to be bigger. initial-scale is a must though

Answer (score 1):

Possibly use [JavaScript](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) to detect the browser and then use [devicePixelRatio](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/07/more_about_devi.html) to determine the screen resolution?

Or maybe, you could just use media queries to achieve what you want?

- [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/)
- [Marc Edwards github](https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599) from the post [device pixel
  density tests](http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/) also mentioned by [Teo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2382115/teo-dragovic) in a comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you Karington,

Don't deal with other complicated instant CSS and JS files. You can make your own web site as you want.

Use these media queries:

[Media Queries for Web Design](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

and design your site.

Then check your process step by step on this link:

[Test your Responsive Web Design](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/)

Here is a web page that I designed in one day with this two link:

[Lottery Query for Turkish People](http://dahaoncecikmismi.com/)

I hope these two link will help you.